Find all the eigenvalues of this complex invertible matrix
I found this Linear Algebra exercise and  I'm kind of stuck. Here's the exercise in question:
We are given a complex invertible matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb C )$, so that the sum of the elements in each column is equal to $k\neq 0$, and we are asked to find all of its eigenvalues.
Right below I present my current effort:
I set $A=(z_{ij})$ and firstly considered an arbitrary eigenvalue, say $λ$. Hence, there a exists a non zero complex column vector $0\neq v \in M_{n×1}(\mathbb C)$ such that $Av=λv$.  Now, if we set $v=(v_i )$, we get that $\sum_{j=1}^n{z_{ij}v_j}=λv_i$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$. Therefore, since
$\sum_{i=1}^n{z_{ij}}=k$ for all $j=1,2,...,n$ we have that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n{kv_j}=\sum_{j=1}^n{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{z_{ij}}\right) v_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n{z_{ij}v_j}\right)}=\sum_{i=1}^n{λv_i},$$
meaning that
$$\left( λ-k \right) \sum_{i=1}^n{v_i}=0,$$
and so either $λ=k$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n{v_i}=0$.
Now my problem is that I don't know what to do with the latter case, but I suppose that it has something to do with $A$ being invertible, since I haven't used that fact yet. In particular, I conjecture that this case is impossible. However, I'm unable to deduce that part.
NOTE
Do not worry about the converse, since it is a common and simple exercise in its own right and I've already done some research on that, thus it need not be discussed any further.

Consider a special case of a special case where $A$ is known to be a permutation matrix ($k=1$).  Can you now deduce all the eigenvalues of $A$?  Absolutely not, so there is something wrong with your problem statement.

The fact that every column adds up to $k$ tell you that $k$ is an eigenvalue: it is an eignevalue of $A^T$ with eigenvector $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$, and $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues (since they have the same characteristic polynomial). But if this is the only thing you know, then it is not enough to determine all eigenvalues.

@user8675309 If the problem statement is wrong, then it's not my fault because I found it as an exercise. Also, I don't know what a permutation matrix is.

@ArturoMagidin Yes, that's what the note I left was about, that k is in fact an eigenvector. But, the problem specifically asked to determine all eigenvalues. Now, I don't know if the author of the book I found this exercise in made a mistake or not.

Well, you never actually said that $k$ was an eigenvalue. You concluded that either $k$ was an eigenvalue or that the sum of the entries of the eigenvector are zero.  If there is really no other information, then you cannot determine the eigenvalues:take any invertible probability matrix $A$, and then $kA$ will have the given property. We know stuff about those other eigenvalues (they all have complex norm less than or equal to $1$, for example), but you can find matrices with all kinds of eigenvalues.

@ArturoMagidin Well, I checked the problem statement again, and still said to find the eigenvalues of A. Now, perhaps the structure of the complex numbers only allows for k to be the only eigenvalue or the author phrased it incorrectly.

The issue is not necessarily what it asks you to do, but what information it gave you about $A$. No, "the structure of the complex numbers" does not "allow for $k$ to be the only eigenvalue." The previous comment tells you how to find lots of examples of different matrices that satisfy the assumptions but whose sets of eigenvalues are different from each other. E.g., you could have $k$ times the identity. But you could also have the probability matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}k/2 & k/2& 0\ k/2 & 0 & k/2\ 0&k/2&k/2\end{array}\right)$, with eigenvalues $k$, $k/2$, $-k/2$.

@ArturoMagidin Well, this actually settles it once and for all. The problem is impossible.
